# Can I force my Android app to update from the Play Store?

Tags: java, android, google-play, auto-update

I fear my users will ignore my latest app updates if they don't think they're necessary.

The app is downloaded from the Google Play store, is there any way I can force updates of my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the solution that `Gabe Sechan` suggested, now you can use the [Google Play In-app Updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates) feature.

Comment: Yeah, this didn't exist 3 years ago when I wrote my answer, but it's the better solution now.

Answer (score 2):

The user has control of whether to enable auto-update or not.  You cannot force them.  If the app has no server interactivity, there's nothing you can do.  If the app does have server interactivity, send the version up with each request, and if the version is too low send an error response back.  The client should then interpret that error response and show a "Must update" screen